# How to remove bottom padding of List and ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'd like to remove bottom padding, the white space between the red space. Is there any way to achieve it?

[image]

**Test Code:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // the same result with using List instead of ScrollView
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(1..<100) { index in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(index)")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.background(Color.red)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Test")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to pass `0` for no spacing. By default it takes default space based on context. The same result will be for List instead of ScrollView.

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
   VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(items) { item in

        // your code here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and this isn’t the case? There’s still a gap between the bottom of the List view and the next view whether or not it’s embedded in a VStack with 0 spacing. See here because I’m trying to solve something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579763/how-to-have-2x2-made-of-squares-fit-screen-in-swiftui

Comment: It works but VStack should be inside of ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Just use GeometryReader

```
@State var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

ScrollView {
    YourContentView()
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.clear.onAppear {
                    contentSize = geo.size
                }
            }
        )
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: contentSize.height)
```