# How to have 2x2 made of squares fit screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-layout

I'm trying to create a 2x2 grid through either VStacks/HStacks or LazyVGrid to have the squares on each row fit the screen. For example, the first and second squares each take up half the width of the screen and based on that length, that'll determine the height to make it a square. How would I go about doing that in the two ways that I've mentioned or is there a better way to do it? Here's what I have so far.

```swift
VStack {
    HStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    HStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

[image: Stacks]

It feels wrong to hardcode the width and height for the frame property here or is that the way to go about removing the gaps between the squares? Would this way of hardcoding values scale to other phone sizes?

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: layout) {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.gray)
        .frame(width: 210, height: 210)
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .frame(width: 210, height: 210)
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 210, height: 210)
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.green)
        .frame(width: 210, height: 210)
}
```

[image: LazyVGrid]

EDIT: Here's what the new code looks like to get what I wanted.

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.gray)

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)

    }
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)

    }
}
.aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
```

[image]

Now to get it working with LazyVGrid.

Comment: You can use UIScreen.main.bounds.width if you only support portrait mode

Comment: @SwiftiSwift that’s a good one to know. I didn’t know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the `aspectRatio` (value 1 and fit the screen) modifier, there is no need to specify any frame.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.gray)
            
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            
    }
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            
    }
}
.aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: No value needed. ContentMode is enough `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`

Comment: @Leo I know, The value makes it clearer for the OP

Comment: @vadian thank you. This helped. What was left was to add `spacing: 0` to the VStack and the two HStacks.

Answer (score 2):

> It feels wrong to hardcode the width and height for frame here or is that the way to go about removing the gaps between the squares?

To remove the gaps between the squares, just modify the HStack / VStack to include spacing:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, content: {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GeometryReader`, as seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader).

Example usage:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
       GeometryReader { geo in
           //You now have access to geo.size.width and geo.size.height
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SwiftiSwift why? There is no need to query the screen size